# Unable to run anchor build due to out-of-date rustc version, although I have the required rustc version on my machine

Tags: anchor, solana

I'm trying to run anchor build, but am running into an issue that says my version for rustc is outdated, although I have the right version on my machine. The device is a Mac with M1 chip.

```
solana % rustc --version
rustc 1.68.0....
solana % anchor build
BPF SDK: .../.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.29/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: package `anchor-attribute-constant v0.27.0` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.60 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.59.0-dev
```

I've read other posts and tried the following commands:

```
solana-install update

sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.9.13/install)"

solana-install init 1.9.13
```

But none of these have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Solana latest version instead of 1.9.13

`sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.15.2/install)"` - this worked for me